# Can't use util/delay.h on c++ in Avrstudio v6

Tags: c++, atmel-studio

I'm just new with microcontrollers and I'm hoping someone could help me understand this. I'm using an AVRStudio 6 and an AVRDragon. Watched some tutorials on basic programming.

Here's the code:

```
#include <util/delay.h>
int main(void) {
    _delay_ms(30);
}
```

What I can't understand is when I made a new avrgcc c project it works well. But as a c++ fan, I made a new project using avrgcc c++ and the code won't work.
The error message is as follows:

```
2. 'fabs' was not declared in this scope
3. 'ceil' was not declared in this scope
4. 'fabs' was not declared in this scope
5. 'ceil' was no declared in this scope
```

I tried those codes  in my avrsudio v6 by avrgcc c++ program and the warning #1 goes away but the other 4 warnings are still there? If I use avrgcc c there are no problems.
What must I do so I could do this with avrgcc c++?
Can anyone help me understands whats going on?
Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1):

According to this link:

[www.avrfreaks.net/comment/683718#comment-683718](http://www.avrfreaks.net/comment/683718#comment-683718)

I added :

```
#include <math.h>
```

to the ***delay.h*** file header, and this erro fixed.

Thanks ***www.avrfreaks.net***